# Sum distinct by separate ID column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have some data of the form:

```
ID  Value
A   2
B   2
C   3
A   2
A   2
C   3
B   2
```

I want to sum `value` by distinct IDs.

select `sum(distinct value) from table` would give the sum of 2 and 3 = 5. I don't want that, I want the sum of value for each ID, i.e. A=2, B=2, C=3, there's 3 distinct IDs so sum(2,2,3) = 7.

In 'sql-ish' I want something like select `sum(distinct value by ID) from table`. Is this possible?

Comment: With the data set that you provided, what is the full expected result? A = 6, B = 4, C = 6 ?

Comment: @Jake Expected result is 7. Sum of 2,2 and 3. Trying to avoid a subquery if possible for reasons that would involve larger explanation and I'm trying to keep this post minimalistic. Ideally looking for a way to tell sql to do this within the sum() function rather than subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the distinct combinations of `ID` and `Value` in a subquery and then the sum of `Value`s:

```
SELECT SUM(Value) sum_value
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID, Value FROM tablename) t
```

Another way to do it is with `SUM()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM(MAX(Value)) OVER() sum_value
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=199323cfc8964c1c53befdea3f2b6974).

Comment: Thanks for this! Just trying to read and interpret your second option What's happening with `... OVER() sum_value`? Is `sum_value` an alias here?

Comment: @user14328853 yes it is the alias of the sum.

Comment: Hmm, I have never encountered this OVER() function. Time to do some research.